# C# call to C and pass parameter as a pointer to an array

Tags: c#, c++, c, marshalling

I have a C method with the following signature:

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) int my_func
    (const double(*points)[3], double parameters[MAXPARS], int* numberofparameters);
```

This function is part of a .lib, which I'm wrapping in a DLL (CLR/CLI) written in C++, so that I can call from C#.
The signature of the C++ method is similar:

```
int MyFunc(const double(*points)[3],
            double parameters[MAXPARS],
            int* numberofparameters)
```

Now my difficulty is how to call this method from C#. The problem is the first parameter, const double(*points)[3], which I don't know how to pass.
My code in C# looks like:

```
double[,] pts = new double[1,3];
pts[0, 0] = 1.5;
pts[0, 1] = 2.5;
pts[0, 2] = 3.5;

double[] parameters = new double[4];
int nrParams;
unsafe {
    fixed (double *points = pts) {
       fixed (double* para = &parameters[0]) {
          wrapper.MyFunc(&points, para, &nrParams);
       }

    }
}
```

This shows the error:
Argument 1: cannot convert from double** to < CppImplementationDetails >$ArrayType ....

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Greetings,

```
Sorin
```

Comment: C or C++? You say C in your title, you say that you "have a C method", and then you speak of C++, and you've tagged C++ as well.

Comment: right, because I am wrapping the C method into a C++ DLL, like I said; the C++ method has the same signature as the C one

Comment: `double parameters[MAXPARS]` – note that the given length parameter is ignored entirely, the expression is equivalent to `double parameters[]` or `double* parameters`. If you placed in awareness of that for documentation purposes it's fine, but further expectations on your side wouldn't get satisfied. Note, too, that first parameter differs in this respect (pointer to array of size 3).

Comment: It is just the same in C or C++: `double* p = ...; double** pp = &p; /* fine */; double a[3]; double (*pa)[3] = &a; /* fine */; pp = &a; /* differing pointer types! */ pa = &p; /* differing pointer types */`

Comment: the question was how to call that from C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a C++/CLI wrapper, I would adjust the API there and make that one more C#-ish.

So change the C++/CLI declaration to something like:

```cpp
int MyFunc(array<double>^ points,
            array<double>^ parameters);
```

and then do all the managed->unmanaged wrapping in that implementation.

In the end, it would look something like this:

```cpp
int MyFunc(array<double>^ points,
    array<double>^ parameters)
{

    if (points->Length != 3)
    {
        throw gcnew System::ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Expecting exactly 3 points");
    }

    double *pPoints = (double*)alloca(sizeof(double) * points->Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < points->Length; i++)
    {
        pPoints[i] = points[i];
    }

    double* pParams = (double*)alloca(sizeof(double) * parameters->Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < parameters->Length; i++)
    {
        pParams[i] = parameters[i];
    }

    double(*pPoints3)[3] = (double(*)[3])pPoints;
    int numParams = parameters->Length;
    my_func(pPoints3, pParams, &numParams);
}
```

However, I'm completely confused on the line with the ??? as I don't exactly know what `const double(*pPoints3)[3]` means. An array of 3 doubles? Or an array of pointers to doubles?

Comment: Thank you, that could be a way. I still have issues though converting array< double >^ from C++ to the double(*points)[3] in C. Could you please be more specific ?

Comment: @Sorin-AlexandruCristescu I have extended the answer, however I'm stuck with the first argument. Do you have the possibility to look into the C code to see what that parameter actually is?

Comment: it is a pointer to an array; each item in the array is a triplet: 
c = malloc(sizeof(double[3]) * size);
then, this "c" contains triplets, e.g. (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), etc.

Comment: Then maybe it's correct like this, but I'm not sure. It's possible that you have to handle it as a stagged array.

Comment: It is correct, thanks. I would have expected to be able to pass a parameter from C# that would simply translate to double(*pPoints)[3] in C/C++, but this is good enough for me.